# Can I pass a number as a key in a data-object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use ruby templates to generate a link. This works:

```
  <% link_to t('features.cta_link')+link_id('features'),
    data: { test: t('header.button') } do %>
```

But I would like to set the data-attribute data-2 so I tried

```
  <% link_to t('features.cta_link')+link_id('features'),
    data: { 2: t('header.button') } do %>
```

but then I get

```
unexpected ':', expecting => ...ion', itemscope: '', data: { 2: t('header.button') } do ... ^
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass a number?

Answer (score 2):

I need to use the regular syntax:

```
{ 2 => t('header.button') }
```

Comment: faced the same issue few days ago, data seems to not accept new ruby syntax

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I don't think `{ 2: ... }` is valid ruby syntax

Comment: @Stefan, I am pretty sure `2:` is invalid Ruby syntax, I meant in general  `:` vs `=>`.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko There's nothing special about the `data` attribute. Whether you can use the alternate hash syntax depends on your Ruby version.

Comment: @Stefan I've not been able to use alternate hash syntax in HAML file (inside `data {}` ) using ruby 2.2.2, but changing it to old hashrocket one allowed my to pass what I wanted